# Initializing a container of pointers to class objects?

Tags: c++

So I've been asked as part of a college project to create an Email class containing a variable that is a container to Attachment objects. The problem is that everytime I try to debug the project is gives me an error 'Attachment *const ': unknown size. I know I forward declared the Attachment class in the Email class but if I replace it with include "Attachment.h" it gives me more errors saying it can't find Attachment and it's not declared. There's no pointers in the vector as it also just gave a tonne of errors. Here's the code:

Email.h

```
 #pragma once
 class Attachment;
 class Email
 {
 private:
     std::string sender;
     std::string recipients;
     std::string dateTime;
     std::string subject;
     std::string body;
     std::vector<Attachment> attVec;

 public:
     Email();

     Email(std::string sender, std::string recipients, std::string dateTime,             
     std::string subject, std::string body, std::vector<Attachment> attVec);

     ~Email();

     bool validate(std::string regexStr, std::string data);

     std::string getSender() { return this->sender; }
     std::string getRecipients() { return this->recipients; }
     std::string getDateTime() { return this->dateTime; }
     std::string getSubject() { return this->subject; }
     std::string getBody() { return this->body; }
     std::vector<Attachment>getAttVec() { return this->attVec; }

     void setSender(std::string sender);
     void setRecipient(std::string recipients);
     //Must change
     void setDateTime(std::string dateTime) { this->dateTime = dateTime; }
     void setSubject(std::string subject) { this->subject = subject.size() 
     >= 0; }
     void setBody(std::string body) { this->body = body.size() >= 1; }
     void setAttVec(std::vector<Attachment>getAttVec) { this->attVec.size() 
     >= 1; }
 };
```

Attachment.h

```
#pragma once

class Attachment
{

private:
    std::string fileName;
    std::string fileSuffix;
    const char* fileData;

public:
    Attachment();

    Attachment(std::string fileName, std::string fileSuffix, const char*         
    fileData);

    ~Attachment();

    bool validate(std::string regexStr, std::string data);

    std::string getFileName() { return this->fileName; }
    std::string getFileSuffix() { return this->fileSuffix; }
    const char* getFileData() { return this->fileData; }

    void setFileName(std::string fileName);
    void setFileSuffix(std::string fileSuffix);
    void setFileData(const char* fileData) { this->fileData != NULL; }
};
```

Comment: What line gives you the error?

Comment: `Attachment.h` should be included in `Email.h` instead of the forward declaration. You probably are doing something wrong with the `.cpp` files or other includes.

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: The error is coming from the vector line 1704, presuming that's coming from the vector include in the pch.h file. I've tried that but it gives me more errors.

Comment: @SeanMorrissey You are referring only to part of the error message. It will also reference a line in your code (because the error will almost surely not be in the library code). The fact that you get more errors with the include doesn't change that it is correct. The error is somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

The error is being throw by the last line in the `Email.h` file
`void setAttVec(std::vector<Attachment>getAttVec) { this->attVec.size() >= 1; }`

To solve this issue you have to include the class `Attachment` with `#include "Attachment.h"`, now this is not advised in `.h` files because it can cause circular dependencies, that's why you should use forward declaration, like you do. The problem is that the `Email` class still has no idea what an object of the class `Attachment` can do.
You have two options, if you are sure that you won't have circular dependencies you can put the include statement on the `Email.h` file, if not (and usually the best option) you should do all the "work" (accessing any object of this class) on objects of the `Attachment` class in the `Email.cpp` file, there you could put the `#include "Attachment.h"` without any problems.

I get that maybe you think that you don't need to have a `.cpp` file, because the methods are simple enough (at least the ones we see), but to have all in  one `.h` file you must ensure no circular dependency, otherwise if you split them it can make your life easier and the class will be more organized (if it gets more complex).

## Updated following comments

So I've tested your code and I'm able to create and object of the `Email` class and one of `Attachment` class, the code compiles and runs fine, so the problem as to be a conflict with the rest of the code, here is a link where you can check the code running. [Email Project](https://repl.it/@Aandree05/SOEmail)

I still had to make changes to your code to make it work, I don't know if you have a `Attachment.cpp` file, if you do this two probably you don't need to do.

```
Attachment(std::string fileName, std::string fileSuffix, const char*         
fileData);

~Attachment();
```

The constructor and destructor have no body (if you have the body on the `.cpp` file consider being consistent and put the body from each function there).

```
Attachment(std::string fileName, std::string fileSuffix, const char* fileData)
{
  this->fileName = fileName;
  this->fileSuffix = fileSuffix;
  this->fileData = fileData;
}

~Attachment(){};
```

On you `Email.h` file I had to add three includes, `#include <string>` , `#include <vector>` and `#include <regex>` (maybe you add then somewhere else, but if you don't you need to have them and it would be a good idea to have them on each file you need, because if you later delete them from where you have them because you don't need them there this class will give errors)

#### Note

On you `Email.cpp` file you have the following function function that is literally doing nothing (maybe was just for some kind of testing).

```
void Email::setAttVec(std::vector<Attachment> getAttVec)
{
    this->attVec.size() >= 1;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment so I've moved the #include "Attachment.h" into the Email.cpp file but it's giving me more errors saying one or more multiply defined symbols found. Now I know that means I'm declaring my .h file more than once somewhere but I just don't know where

Comment: @SeanMorrissey No `multiply defined symbols` means that you defined something in two translation units that shouldn't be defined in two translation units. Again, the source of all these issue will be that you do something wrong with the `.cpp` files or that you define something in a header file which should be defined in a `.cpp` file. How often something is included in one translation unit does not matter, because the error would be at compile-time, not link-time like yours.

Comment: @SeanMorrissey Can you show us your `Email.cpp` file? Also when you put the `#include Attachment.h` in the `Email.cpp` file do you leave this line the same?  `void setAttVec(std::vector<Attachment>getAttVec) { this->attVec.size() >= 1; }`

Comment: I've posted my email.cpp file boelow. And yes I did originally but I've now ut it into the .cpp file.